# Which constructor is better for StreamResult()?

Tags: java, performance

It's my first time posing a question here. I would like to know which constructor is better in terms of performance for a large xml dom to be written to a test.xml file:

```
new StreamResult(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test.xml"), "UTF-8")))
```

Or

```
new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("test.xml"))
```

Regarding setting the UTF-8 encoding, what happens in the second case where it's not specified for an OutputStream? (Edit: This is answered but not the performance part yet)

[StreamResult Constructor JavaDoc Link](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html#StreamResult%28java.io.OutputStream%29)

Thanks

Comment: PS: Also, I'm feedng this through to a Transformer which sets the encoding through:
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoding is done through Transformer. The Transformer may use instructions contained in the transformation instructions to control the encoding.

Comment: +1. Which is why it's generally preferred to use `new StreamResult(OutputStream))` constructor. BufferedWriter should not make a big difference, but if you're so concerned about performance - measure it for both cases and choose the better one.